# Lowest ranked items out of those which have been ranked x times

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a sql dataset that look like this

Table `df1`:

```
+-----+------+---------+
| Key | Name | Ranking |
+-----+------+---------+
|   1 | A    |       2 |
|   2 | B    |       4 |
|   1 | A    |       3 |
+-----+------+---------+
```

I want to find the lowest ranked item which has been ranked atleast 5 times.

This is the code I have so far but it doesnt seem to work:

```
select 
     Key,
     Name,
     Ranking,
     sum(Ranking) 
from 
     table 
Group BY 
     key
Where 
     Count(Ranking)>5
```

Comment: @Brien I was just using that for playing around, my bad, I have fixed it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[example]](http://rextester.com/DPO69623)

```
SELECT
     key_,
     Name,
     MAX(Ranking),
     MIN(Ranking) 
FROM 
     df1 
GROUP BY key_ 
HAVING COUNT(Ranking) >= 5;
```

As you'll see in the example/demo, the first query on the table with no key having at least 5 rankings results in no rows. Then I've inserted 4 more records for key_=5 and then queried again, retrieving the result:

[image]

(included `MAX()` for the other `Ranking` in your example because you weren't using an `ORDER BY` so the result for `Ranking` in that case 'could' be random.)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation!

Comment: @Skyhopper9 you are welcome. I am happy to help and glad you’ve found a few ways to do this now.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this:

```
SELECT
     id,
     Name,
     MIN(Ranking)   
FROM 
     table 
Group BY id 
HAVING SUM(Ranking) >= 5;
```

Comment: Yes it seems to works, thanks. However, I just have a doubt, shouldn't it be COUNT instead of sum as I want the number of ranking to be greater than 5?